# Form doesn't work when adding :remote => true

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

It's not the only remote form I'm using, but I can't see the problem here. It's a simple table where every row has its own form and inline form fields.

```
<% for temporary_address in @temporary_addresses %>

    <tr id="row-<%= temporary_address.id -%>">
        <%= form_for temporary_address, :remote => true do |form| %>

            <td>
                <%= link_to "x", temporary_address, :method => :delete, :remote => true %>
                <%= form.submit "s" %>
            </td>

            [... form fields ...]
        <% end %>
    </tr>

<% end %>
```

However, this only works when :remote => true is **not** used.

```
resources :temporary_addresses
```

is in the routes file. Delete links are working and the form is also working when not using :remote => true.

pressing submit **with remote => true** gives

```
Started POST "/temporary_addresses/12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-17 12:45:26 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/temporary_addresses/12")
```

and submitting **without remote => true** works with the following response

```
Started POST "/temporary_addresses/12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-17 12:46:15 +0200
  Processing by TemporaryAddressesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {[...] "commit"=>"s", "temporary_address"=>{[...]}, "id"=>"12"}
```

does someone have a clue about this?

**EDIT 1**
Removed the link_to :remote to destroy a record to check. Same error...

A rendered form looks like this:

```
<tr id="row-1">
    <td>
    </td>

    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/temporary_addresses/1" class="edit_temporary_address" data-remote="true" id="edit_temporary_address_1" method="post">

        <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
            <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="vpFbYO7L9fVtBsWej37FUBobraYjjdWA/F8AjWTwC7A=" />
        </div>

            <td>
                <input id="temporary_address_firstname" name="temporary_address[firstname]" size="30" type="text" value="John" />
            </td>
            <td>

                <input id="temporary_address_lastname" name="temporary_address[lastname]" size="30" type="text" value="Doe" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="temporary_address_email" name="temporary_address[email]" size="30" type="text" value="john.doe@example.com" />
            </td>
            <td>
                    New record
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="temporary_address_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="save" />
            </td>

        </form>
</tr>
```

Comment: Rails determines the actual method by a parameter called '_method'. I looks like this param is actually missing when you send the request via javascript. Can you post your rails.js and possible an example of a rendered form?

Comment: Any chance you have a button_to somewhere within your form that also has a `:remote => true` in it?

Comment: @dylan there's the link_to delete which is also remote. and that's it.

Comment: @mosch will do this later, thanks

Comment: @dylan removed link_to for testing. same result. @mosch added a rendered form output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Simple thing.. Firefox rearranges things when they're not valid html. The output given above is the source code. Now that I've seen the generated source code (thanks to web development toolbar) the problem is clear: The hidden form fields, generated in divs with display:none have been moved outside of the form.